# mouseover actionscript

Tags: actionscript, event-handling, onmouseover

I am designing a page in flex and I have a one image. Specific text should be shown when user hovers mouse to the image. Here is my actionScript code that I wrote but it is not working (it is not showing text on mouseOver event:(

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="100" minHeight="100">
<fx:Script>
    private var helpText:String = "Some Text."      
    private function helpIconEvent(e:MouseEvent):void{              
        if(e.type == "mouseOver"){
            e.currentTarget.helpText.visible = true;                            
        }
    }       
    private function addEventToHelpIcon():void {
        helpIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, helpIconEvent);
    }
</fx:Script>        

<mx:Image id="helpIcon" x="270" y="187" width="50" height="50" mouseOver="addEventToHelpIcon"
          source="source_path"/>
```

Any help/insight will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: first you should create new `text` element that have `id='helpText'`

Comment: I have already done it:::: private var helpText:String = "Some Text."

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

- You are not adding the mouse over listener correctly. You are actually adding two event listeners, one in MXML and then when that event happens you add the second one.  Just use the MXML listener (see below).
- In function that runs when the mouse over happens, you are trying to set the `visible` property on a String object.  A String by itself will not display anything. You can display the String with a Label object, in a tool-tip, or some other GUI object.  You need to figure out the right GUI object to use and pass the text to that object.

Here's a very simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           minWidth="100" minHeight="100">
<fx:Script>

    private function onMouseOver():void {
        helpLabel.visible=true;
    }

    private function onMouseOut():void {
        helpLabel.visible=false;
    }

</fx:Script>        

<s:Image id="helpIcon" x="270" y="187"
         width="50" height="50"
         mouseOver="onMouseOver()" mouseOut="onMouseOut()"
         source="source_path"/>

<!-- note the mouse event handlers are so simple in this case, you can also do them in line -->

<s:Image id="alternateMethod" mouseOver="helpLabel.visible=true;"
         mouseOut="helpLabel.visible=false;" />

<s:Label id="helpLabel" x="100" y="100" visible="false" text="Some Text."/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Hello Sunil..Thank you very much. Great help. My code is now working. Also thanks a ton for responding me promptly!!

Answer (score 0):

It think your code should be more like this, but I'm not used to flex so bear with me if I'm wrong.

```
private function foo(e:MouseEvent):void {
if(e.type == MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER)
       //Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding promptly. I tried that too but no difference:(

Comment: By the way, where should the help text display? In the code you only have a variable defining helptext, but you never place it on the "scene" as far as I understand. Have tried using trace(); to make sure that your event fires properly?